# Webpack for backend node work?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to follow [James Long's article](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I) to get my node server code bundled with webpack. My config is below. I'm able to package things trouble-free, but I can't figure out how to make the thing start. For a test, I created a simple server.ts, that just has `console.log('test');`. Webpack hapily compiles it to this;

```
exports.ids = [0,1];
exports.modules = [
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    console.log('test');


/***/ }
];;
```

Problem is, node server.bundle.js does nothing -- which makes sense, since I now export a function that's never called.. I must be missing something obvious, but after two hours of staring at it, I cave.. anyone have any advice?

```
{
        target: 'node',
        entry: {
            'server': Path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'server.ts')
        },
        output: {
            path: Path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: '[name].bundle.js'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.json', '.ts']
        },
        devtool: 'source-map',
        module: {
            preLoaders: [
                {test: /\.ts$/, loader: "tslint"}
            ],
            loaders: [
                {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'script'},
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    query: {
                        configFileName: 'server/tsconfig.json',
                        ignoreDiagnostics: [
                            2403, // 2403 -> Subsequent variable declarations
                            2300, // 2300 -> Duplicate identifier
                            2374, // 2374 -> Duplicate number index signature
                            2375  // 2375 -> Duplicate string index signature
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'raw'}
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new Webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common', 'common.bundle.js')
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was the problem;

```
plugins: [
            new Webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common', 'common.bundle.js')
]
```

For anyone that stumbles on this, for backend code, don't optimize the common, it has the loader code and won't work.

Answer (score -4):

Do not use webpack as a compiler for backend / nodejs code. That is not its intended use. Just run `tsc -w` to get the JS or if you are feeling funky (don't want js resources lying around) give `ts-node` a go : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node